# Add / collate QGIS layer to existing PostGIS table?

Tags: qgis, postgis

With the database manager in QGIS, it is possible to export a QGIS layer to a PostgreSQL database, by creating a new table in the database. For instance, if I have a `cities` layer in my QGIS project, I can export it to a new table `cities` in my PostgreSQL database.

The tool provides the option of replacing the destination table in the database, if this table already exists (see screenshot below, sorry about the French locale).

Now, my question is: **is there any way to "concatenate" the data of my QGIS layer** `cities` **to the existing** `cities`**table of my PostgreSQL database**, instead of erasing the existing table and replacing it by a new one?

*(assuming of course, that the existing database table and the QGIS layers have the same CRS and the same geometry type)*

[image]